# Spark Streaming - Is there a way to Union two JavaInputDstreams, perform a transformation on unified stream and commit offset

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

The spark consumer have to read topics with same name from different Bootstrap servers. So in need to create two JavaDstreams, performing union, process the stream and commit the offsets.

```
JavaInputDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord>> dStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...);
```

Problem is JavaInputDStream doesn't support `dStream.Union(stream2)`;

If i use,

```
JavaDStream<ConsumerRecord<String, GenericRecord>> dStream= KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(...);
```

But JavaDstream doesn't support,

```
((CanCommitOffsets) dStream.inputDStream()).commitAsync(os);
```

Answer (score 0):

Please bare with the long answer.

There is no direct way to do this which i am aware of so, I would like to first convert the Dstreams to Datasets/Dataframes and then perform a UNION on both of the dataframes/datasets.

The below code is not tested but this should works. Please feel free to validate and do the necessary changes to make it work.

```
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> pairDstream1 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,kafkaParams, topics);
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> pairDstream2 = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc,kafkaParams, topics);

//Create JavaDStream<String>
JavaDStream<String> dstream1 = pairDstream1.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
      return tuple2._2();
    }
  });

//Create JavaDStream<String>
JavaDStream<String> dstream1 = pairDstream2.map(new Function<Tuple2<String, String>, String>() {
    @Override
    public String call(Tuple2<String, String> tuple2) {
      return tuple2._2();
    }
  });


//Create JavaRDD<Row>
pairDstream1.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
      @Override
      public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) { 
  JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = rdd.map(new Function<String, Row>() {
      @Override
      public Row call(String msg) {
Row row = RowFactory.create(msg);
return row;
      }
    });

 //Create JavaRDD<Row>
pairDstream2.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
      @Override
      public void call(JavaRDD<String> rdd) { 
  JavaRDD<Row> rowRDD = rdd.map(new Function<String, Row>() {
      @Override
      public Row call(String msg) {
Row row = RowFactory.create(msg);
return row;
      }
    });
//Create Schema       
StructType schema = DataTypes.createStructType(new StructField[] {DataTypes.createStructField("Message", DataTypes.StringType, true)});
//Get Spark 2.0 session       
SparkSession spark = JavaSparkSessionSingleton.getInstance(rdd.context().getConf());
Dataset<Row> df1 = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);
Dataset<Row> df2 = spark.createDataFrame(rowRDD, schema);
//union the both dataframes
df1.union(df2);
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I will test the code and see if it works for me.

Comment: The problem is, i want to commit offsets once, i finish the transformation, Which is supported only on JavaInputDStream.

Comment: Not necessarily you can get the offset ranges and store them in a database like HBase and then continue with your processing or transformation. Once this is done you can commit all the offsets. 

stream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {
  OffsetRange[] offsetRanges = ((HasOffsetRanges) rdd.rdd()).offsetRanges();

  // some time later, after outputs have completed
  ((CanCommitOffsets) stream.inputDStream()).commitAsync(offsetRanges);
});

Comment: BTW, you did not mention that you need to commit offsets manually in your question.